# image vertical align bootstrap with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know the proper way to put an image in the center of the page, and then beside the image vertical align 2 lines of text. should I put the image and text in one bootstrap coloumn or should i have the image in one coloumn and the text in a seperate coloumn. I know there are a few ways to do this, i just want to know the proper method.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" style="vertical-align:middle" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <span style="font-size:48px;">Test</span>
    <span style="font-size:24px;">Test second line. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k90s5fec/

Comment: you have included bootstrap css in jsfiddle?

Comment: is that unnecessary?

Comment: yes it is without that its not display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do this

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" style="vertical-align:middle" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p style="font-size:48px;">Test</p>
    <p style="font-size:24px;">Test second line. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k90s5fec/2/)

**NOTE** :  Use `https://` when importing external resources, 
use `p` tag instead of `span` if you want to use block texts.

Comment: Thanks Jinu that works, so the correct way is to use two seperate coloumns then and display them in an inline block?

Comment: @jsandrails Yes, you can do other way around too. But having separate columns will give you more control !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
           <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" class="displa`enter code here`yed" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
           <span style="font-size:48px;">Test</span>
           <span style="vertical-align:middle; line-height: 30px;">Test second line. </span>
      </div>
 </div>

 img.displayed 
 {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" style="vertical-align:middle" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div style="font-size:48px;">Test</div>
    <div style="font-size:24px;">Test second line. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```